# Get data from a promise. Or is it promise at all?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I store some data in IndexedDB and i use npm package localforage for it.

```
const retrieveData = async () => {
  const keys = await localforage.keys()
  const data = await keys.map(async (key) => {
    const item = await localforage.getItem(key)
    return [item.username, item.compamy, item.email, item.lastUpdate]
  })
  return data
}
```

Whenever I execute this function, I get a resolved Promise object, which values I cannot extract

```
async componentDidMount() {
  let asyncData = retrieveData()
  console.log(asyncData)  // Promise object
  asyncData = retrieveData().then(values => values)
  console.log(asyncData)  // Promise object anyways
}
```

How exactly should I get data from this Promise object?

Comment: I'd suggest you read about [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/async_function) and [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise). This will help you understand javascript asynchronous nature and why your code is not doing what you expect.

Comment: Either `retrieveData().then(console.log)` or `console.log(await retrieveData())`. Yes, it's a promise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use for of loop here, and it will be simpler, we dont use await keyword directly in a map iterator, instead we can use promise.all as mentioned in above answer.

```
const retrieveData = async () => {
    const keys = await localforage.keys();

    let data;
    for (let key of keys) {
        const item = await localforage.getItem(key);
        data.push([item.username, item.compamy, item.email, item.lastUpdate]);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const retrieveData = async () => {
  const keys = await localforage.keys()
  // The return value of "keys.map" is an array of promises since
  // async automatically returns a Promise behind the scenes.
  // Await works on a single promise, not an array of promises,
  // so "data" will not contain the actual data. 
  const data = await keys.map(async (key) => {
    const item = await localforage.getItem(key)
    return [item.username, item.compamy, item.email, item.lastUpdate]
  })
  return data
}
```

Do:

```
const retrieveData = async () => {
  const keys = await localforage.keys()
  const data = await Promise.all(keys.map(async (key) => {
    const item = await localforage.getItem(key)
    return [item.username, item.compamy, item.email, item.lastUpdate]
  }));
  return data
}
```

[Or use Bluebird's map which works out of the box in this scenario](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html):

```
// The "then" function does not do anything. It returns values,
// but only does so to the next "then" function. There are no
// further then-functions so the return value is unused.
// "values" is merely a local variable so you won't be able to
// access it anywhere outside the fat arrow function.
// You could move the console log into "then".
asyncData = retrieveData().then(values => values) 


// asyncdata is still the unresolved promise object, the "then"
// function has not been run yet (then on the line above will be run when
// all of the awaits in retrieveData have been successfully resolved.
console.log(asyncData)
```

Do:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const data = await retrieveData();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Or:

```
componentDidMount() {
  retrieveData().then(values => {
    console.log(values);
  });
}
```

Comment: Okay, but this returns resolved promise object (was pending promise before), but not data it contains.

Comment: Ah yes didn't look into the retrieveData function. Have a look now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "*await*" reserved keyword before your *retrieveData()* method at *componentDidMount()*, since it's a promise, an async event, you have to wait until it finishes all of it's inner executions to return some data and go on.

Just like you did at *retrieveData()* declaration use **await** before the promise. in detail what you need:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  let asyncData = await retrieveData()
  ....
}
```